# Fresh Laravel install deletes server.php on artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm a bit fresh to Laravel. I installed it via **composer** in the *xampp/htdocs* file. I installed the latest version 5.6.
The install works with no errors, and the file structure is as it should be.

When I run the `php artisan serve` command from inside the folder, it deletes the `server.php` file and therefore outputs the error:

`This site can’t be reached.`

`localhost refused to connect.`

So I thought why not just add a new file inside and it will work... Well, trying to add new file shows that I do not have permissions to add files to this folder.

I tried a new install a few times, but the situation is always the same.

Has anybody else encountered this problem?

Comment: Take a look: http://sforsuresh.in/installing-laravel-5-wamp-xampp/

Comment: That is almost exactly what i did. but then when running php artisan serve, it deletes the server.php file and blocks permission...

Answer (score 1):

So I realised it was some kind of server problem... well, removed the antivirus, chanhed my firewall settings and everithing works as it should.

Comment: It's not a server problem, it's just that the antivirus is deleting the file as it seems to be malicious file in antivirus. What works for me is to disable the antivirus,  rename/paste the file ```server.php```, again enable the antivirus and run the project, if it again shows the file as malicious, choose CREATE EXCEPTION for this file.
Happy Coding !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

My advice to avoid this in the future is to start creating Laravel applications in a folder inside of your `My Documents` folder in Windows or using `/home/{your-username}/projects` directory in Unix environments.

What likely happened is `xampp` has certain permissions that don't play nice with what you need in Laravel.